# Are the cursor marks generated for Solr deep paging deterministic?

Tags: solr

If I use Solr

`query=q with cursorMarks='*'`

and lets say, Solr generates a series of cursor marks as I iterate through those pages

`[CM1, CM2, CM3, ... , CM100]`.

If I stop my Solr deep paging traversal at CM3, would I be able to resume it with CM4 onwards? In short, the series of cursorMarks that Solr generates - are they deterministic as long as the query stays the same and the underlying indexed population of Solr documents does not change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as long as

1. You have a sort defined in your query (and that sort is fixed on each paging call)
2. The sort has a tiebreaker that itself is deterministic (e.g. a unique ID but NOT document id in a SolrCloud environment if there is replication)
3. And as you said the underlying index documents have not changed

As per https://badrit.com/blog/2015/7/26/deep-paging-and-partial-index-export-in-solr#.XE9snc9KiNE

"Deep paging depends on the 'cursor' concept which is a Base64 string representing a logical point in the ordered space of the sort values"

This is also a worthwhile read http://yonik.com/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/